# Dealing with very large vector in R

Tags: r

I am dealing with some large data in R:

I have a vector of normally distributed random numbers with length about 6400*50000, I need to sum every 4 elements in this vector to get a smaller one.

Is there any efficient way to do this in R?

My thoughts till now:

1. using a matrix with ncol=10 and use apply function-- failed because the matrix size is too big;
2. Try paralell and foreach package but no progress yet;

example code:

```
library(parallel)
library(RcppZiggurat)
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)

coreNums<-detectCores()
N1=6400
M=4
N2=N1/M
cl<-makeCluster(getOption("cl.cores", coreNums))
registerDoParallel(cl)
vector1<-zrnorm(N1*K)
vector2=foreach(i=1:(N2*K)) %dopar% {sum(vector1[M*(i-1)+1:M*i])}
vector2=unlist(vector)
```

Comment: Please make this a [reproducible question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by producing a *small* sample vector, your expected output, and what code you've tried so far.

Comment: Updated with a block of codes.

Answer (score 2):

I think `colSums` is the function you are looking for.

```
vector1 = rnorm(1000*50000)
dim(vector1) = c(10, length(vector1)/10)
vector2 = colSums(vector1)
```

In my opinion, the task is too simple for parallelization.
Also, I did not get any problems with the matrix size.

If you want to use less memory, here is the code doing the same in parts of 10,000 values in `vector1`.

```
vector2 = double(length(vector1)/10);
for( i in seq_len(length(vector2)/10000) ){
    part = vector1[((i-1)*10000+1):(i*10000)]
    dim(part) = c(10, 1000)
    vector2[((i-1)*1000+1):(i*1000)] = colSums(part)
}
```

Comment: This works for the case I provided in the question, but if I need larger data, the method can't work. My computer reports"cannot allocate vector of size 7.6 Gb". What should I deal with such question?

Comment: First, my code works on my computer even with `6400 x 50000` matrix. I just have a computer with more memory.

Comment: Second, if you want to use less memory, you can do this task by parts of, say, 10000 values in `vector1`. I'll update the solution.